# Collect personal data in europe using google forms

Tags: security, privacy, data, privacy-policy

Since there have been issues regarding web service providers that store personal/confidential data of users *outside of the European Union*, I am somewhat precarious.

Am I allowed to collect personal data using a [Google Form](https://www.google.com/intl/de_de/forms/about)? I plan to do that for sport event registrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely you can use Google forms. You can use whatever form service you wish to as long as they support storing the collected data within the EU. Googlw achieves compliance with the law through offers to sign [EU Model Contract Clauses](https://www.google.com/intx/en/enterprise/apps/terms/mcc_terms.html) and a [Data Processing Amendment](https://www.google.com/intx/en/enterprise/apps/terms/dpa_terms.html). Google also undergoes independent audits of data protection practices and provides customers with several options to address EU data protection regulations.

This is confirmed by Google at https://support.google.com/work/answer/6056694?hl=en under the heading `How Does Google Adhere to Europeamn Data Protection Requirements?`

Comment: So you have any references to an official statement?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the relevant references as requested.